# Remove Sign in Link in Orchard Footer

Tags: orchardcms

I want to remove the sign in link in the very bottom footer of my Orchard site. I want to go to the link /Users/Account/LogOn to login and not have the link displayed. I don't think its necessary on a public facing site and shouldn't be there.

I can only seem to remove or edit the regular footer. Does anyone know how I can do this?

EDIT - I'd also like to be able to remove the publish date from the content. I don't need the date published to be displayed on a simple about page. Does this functionality exist, is it not intuitive to fix.... or am I just a bit slow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to remove the sign in link in a semi-friendly fashion:

1. Find `Orchard\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Shapes\Views\User.cshtml`
2. Copy it to the `\Views\` directory of the theme you are using
3. Remove the else portion of the branch statement so that it just reads as below.

Hope that helps...

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
     ... blah ...
}
```

Comment: I think it's a bad thing to edit Core sources. It can be done without touching Core.

Comment: The solution provided is the best way to do it and it's *not* bad. You don't change the core source - you copy that file to your theme and edit the copied file. This way you can override any already existing shape with your own implementation without touching the core. (by placing a file with the same name under /Views folder of your theme.). Such file becomes a shape *alternate* and will take precedence over the default one when it comes to rendering the *User* shape.

Comment: These days I think the relevant line is `@if (WorkContext.CurrentUser != null) {`

Answer (score 5):

if you are using Contoso ot TheThemeMachine you can go to the layout.cshtml and remove following line

```
WorkContext.Layout.Footer.Add(New.User(), "10"); // Login and dashboard links
```

That line is responsible for injecting user part into the page

Answer (score 2):

If you are using TheThemeMachine theme, modify the BadgeOfHonor.cshtml in the views directory to modify the footer. To remove the publish date you need to add:

```
<placement>
  <Match ContentType="Page">
      <Match DisplayType="Summary">
        <Place Parts_Common_Metadata="-"/>
      </Match>
      <Match DisplayType="Detail">
        <Place Parts_Common_Metadata="-"/>
      </Match>
    </Match>
</placement>
```

to the Placement.info file, if you do not have one yet, you create one in the root of your theme directory.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Richard Stale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74302/richard-slater) show:

1. Find Orchard\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Shapes\Views\User.cshtml
2. Copy it to the \Views\ directory of the theme you are using
3. **Add in the else portion of the branch statement so that it just reads as below**

`else if (ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue.ToString() != "LogOn")`